# YADR look on Emacs

Tags: emacs, macvim

I just discovered [yadr](http://skwp.github.com/dotfiles) with an amazing look&feel that makes macvim really looks like Emacs:

[image: YADR screenshot]

I was wondering if anybody is aware of a way to make emacs buffer bars having a similar look?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "buffer bars" but if you're talking about vim's statusline in those screenshots then look at [Powerline](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PowerLine) to have Emacs' mode line formatted that way.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was searching for. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally posted this as a comment since I wasn't sure what exactly you were talking about in the screenshot, but since it answers your question I'm posting it as an answer.

The effect you are seeing is the [Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) plugin for vim.  This idea has been ported to Emacs and is available on [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PowerLine).  There are a few forks of this available on GitHub as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many Emacs ports of Powerline, but the most notable is [this one](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline) and [this](https://github.com/jonathanchu/emacs-powerline) being the original port to Emacs. A world of caution though - cool toys like the powerline tend to play bad with some modes and are mostly pretty rather than practical.